# Error from using NBIS in Windows 10

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-10, fingerprint

I built NBIS project (Release 5.0.0 from NIST) in Windows 10 using CygWin (Of course, with CMake, MSYS and WinGW).

However, when I tried to use its commands in CygWin, it turns out that I cannot use them. For example, I tried to use the command *cjpeg* to convert a provided BMP image located in *misc/sivv/data/images* to JPEG, the converted image is created but cannot be opened. Also, the printed log showed errors as follows:

```
//These are some parts of the full log
<standard input>:1390: a special character is invalid within \X
...
<standard input>:1392: cannot use character `:' as a starting delimiter
...
<standard input>:1397: warning: numeric expression expected (got `l')
...
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 2.2i]: cannot adjust line
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 2.3i]: can't break line
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 2.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 2.7i]: can't break line
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 2.8i]: cannot adjust line
<standard input>:1399: warning [p 132, 3.0i]: can't break line
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):400789: X command without `tty:' tag ignored
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):401620: missing argument
```

Another command I tried is *nfiq* for evaluating the provided ANSI/NIST image file and getting a quality value. Using valid1.1.an2 image file located in *misc/an2kconvert/testdata*, the errors is shown as follows:

```
//These are some parts of the full log
1.01:1291.02:02011.03:122004011.04:CAR1.05:199801031.07:ABCDE‐                                            
ä
FGHT1.08:FND‐                                                                                             
ø
JSFHKW1.09:12345678901.11:19.691.12:19.692.001:2312.002:002.005:Y2.009:
A12345678L2.015:AV123452.018:JOHN,CÂIN‐TON2.020:WV2.022:199805072.024:M2
.025:I2.027:5002.029:2002.031:BRO2.032:BLK2.041:10643VAN‐....<U+0094>
ÿÿÿÿÿ^B^B.ÿ ÿ¢^B^B^B2p^D&i....ý¸ÿ¥....<U+0085>
```

(Yes, it cannot be understood.)

For running most of the rest of remaining commands, NBIS replied me back

```
What manual page do you want?
```

As I cannot find any references to these kind of errors, can you give me any advice or suggestion to fix these errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share steps for building NBIS on Windows? Can you somehow share built DLL with me?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share steps for building NBIS on Windows? Can you somehow share built DLL with me?